# How to decide between returning 404 or 405 status on undefined REST routes

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

I'm writing a RESTful API and I have a doubt. I've created a controller that handles requests to undefined resources (I mean incorrect URIs, not correct URIs but with inexistent IDs).

My first intuition was to return a 404 status code to tell the client the resource doesn't exist (on GET requests), but when I started to generalize the logic to handle HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT and other HTTP verbs, I though that maybe the best idea is to return a 405, since in fact, It's not allowed to use these methods (including the GET) on invalid routes.

In the response for the OPTIONS method I'm returning an empty list of allowed methods (I don't include the OPTIONS method neither, even if it's returning a response).

What do you think? Any ideas? I think this field is a little bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my opinion, but I don't think that's the right way to interpret "Method not allowed", otherwise what would be the point of 404? By the same logic, you could also argue it should be 403 since all users are forbidden from performing the action.

I think this method is about the kinds of operations the service supports for *this kind of resource*, not any particular instance of a resource. It shouldn't need to even look up the resource (in general), it just needs to look at the URL and method, and decide if that's an available operation.

For example, a write-only resource could return 405 on a DELETE operation.

Probably the most common use of 405 is when a particular URL is valid, but for another HTTP method than was passed in.